# What is the best python approach/model for clustering dataset with many discrete and categorical variables?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, data-science, cluster-analysis

| Age | Gender | BusinessTravel | Department | Distance | Education | MaritalStatus | Salary | YearsWorked | Satisfaction |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 41 | Female | Frequent | Sales | 12 | 5 | Married | 5000 | 4 | 4 |
| 24 | Male | Rarely | HR | 22 | 4 | Single | 3400 | 1 | 3 |

Satisfaction - Scale from 1 to 5, 5 is the most satisfied.

Distance - Distance from home to workplace

Above is a sample of the data.

*Would Kmeans or Kmodes be appropriate for such a dataset?*

Thank you for any answers in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Kmean clustering would not be ideal as it cannot handle discrete data